# Apply style on hover of an element to another element only if this other element is a child of the hovered element?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have some divs that contain images. When hovered over the divs, the images should rotate in order to create an album like effect.

The method I am trying to use styles the images of all the divs when hovered over any div. I need it to style only the children of the hovered div.

I expect to have more divs and i need this to be done without specifying each div and div child? Is there a smart way to achieve this?

The HTML

```
 <div id="main">
        <div>
            <img src="../img/punime/1cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/2cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/3cc.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../img/punime/1cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/2cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/3cc.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../img/punime/1cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/2cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/3cc.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../img/punime/1cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/2cc.jpg">
            <img src="../img/punime/3cc.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
div#main div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 260px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
    }

div#main div > * {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    }

div#main div:hover + div img:first-child {
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then  you'll need `#main div:hover img { /* styles here */ }`

Comment: Yes. Thanks, it seemed so complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS to

```
#main div:hover img { 
  /* styles here */
}
```

This means: For any `div` within `#main`: style all images that are children of a hovered `div`

### [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/NxRjdo?editors=110)